# Laravel form model binding select2 with ajax

Tags: ajax, forms, laravel, model

I am still new to a bit of this.

I am making and edit form.  I have several select2 boxes.  one is populated via ajax and the others are done through the jquery inital setup.

I am trying to set the default value based on the model.

```
{!! Form::model($printJob, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['PrintJobsController@update', $printJob->print_job_id ], 'class' => 'form-horizontal form-label-left']) !!}

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('mo_id', 'MO Number', ['class'=>'control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12']) !!}
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
        {!! Form::select('mo_id', [], null, ['id' => 'selMoNumber', 'required']) !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

In my scripts i have the initializers

```
$("#selMoNumber").select2({
    language: { errorLoading:function(){ return "Searching..." } },
    dropdownAutoWidth: 'true',
    placeholder: "Enter a MO Number",
    width: '100%',
    ajax: {
        url: "/manufactureorders/query",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 500,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term, // search term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: data,
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    minimumInputLength: 3,
});
```

How do i set the Select2 to be the models value?

Comment: you don't have to use ajax for that...this is done the other way around, you need all the possible select options which you actually have in your create form and then load them into your edit form together with selected item from the model

Comment: so my first question would be where do you get the select options in your create form? do you hard code it or load it from the DB?

Comment: I load it from a database.  There are upwards of 20,000 options which is why i am using the ajax.  I have several other select boxes where i hard code the options in and the model binding works.

Comment: wait a min...you want to say that you have a select box with 20,000 options???

Comment: i use ajax to get max 10 based on the value they type in.  so at most they will see 10 options while they type in which doesnt start till they put in 3 characters.  I dont load all options, hence the ajax.

Comment: maybe because the value that is selected is not loaded you can't see it?